# How to display next 5 records or rows after MySQL query result?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a column in a table that contain words like

1. Abacterial
2. Abactio
3. Abaissement
4. Abalienation
5. Abnet
6. Abaptiston

So, when I query for word ‘Abacterial’ it display result for ‘Abacterial’ but i also want to display next 5 words.

I use this MySQL query code: `mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM medi_words WHERE word LIKE '%$query%'");`

Comment: Try `mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM medi_words WHERE word LIKE '%$query%' LIMIT 5");`?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM medi_words WHERE word >= '$query' LIMIT 5`

Comment: Thanks it works.. thank you very much.

Comment: For extra info on different databases https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp

Answer (score 0):

[Directly from documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM medi_words WHERE word LIKE '%$query%' LIMIT 5";
if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {

    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row["word"]);
    }

    /* free result set */
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}
```